# Is it possible to undo the last command I queued in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Suppose I am in a battle and I play MMM vs Stalker & Immortal. If both armies clash I chain a command to focus all Immortals one after another with Shift.

Sometimes I click 2-3 Immortals and afterwards misclick on the ground. This will either issue the command move or attack ground (nearest enemy) depending on if I issue right click or A + right click. Both versions are not what I want.

Is it possible to undo my last click?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No.

After reviewing the list of command hotkeys I am now certain there there is no way to undo or cancel your last command in Starcraft 2 other than issue a new non-queued command, which will cancel the entire queue.